# How can I fix my slideshow transition error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

I made images and a video slideshow. 3 images and at the end 1 video. It is fine when I made it on a full-screen web page.
But when I made it to half of the screen the transition error showed up, the next image flashed at the bottom of the earlier image.

How can I fix my slideshow transition error?
Can anyone help me?

```js
// Some variables
var timer;
var     sWidth = '100%',
    sHeight = '80%',
  border = 10;
var slideshowSet = false;
var video;
var videoSet = false;
var slidePause = false;
var $el;
var $currentEl = $('.slideshow').find('li').eq(0);

// On document ready
$(function() {
  // Set slideshow dimensions + border
  setSlideDimensions(sWidth, sHeight, border);

  // Show pause button
  $('.slideshow').hover(
    function() {
      if (slideshowSet) {
        $('.pause').stop().fadeIn(200);
      }
    },
    function() {
      if (slideshowSet) {
        $('.pause').fadeOut(200);
      }
    }
  );

  // Pause button
  $('.pause').click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == '| |') {
      // Pause slideshow
      slidePause = true;
      $(this).text('►');
      clearTimeout(timer);
      if ($currentEl.find('video').size() == 1) {
        video.pause();
      }
    } else {
      // Play slideshow
      $(this).text('| |');
      if ($currentEl.find('video').size() == 1) {
        video.play();
      } else {
        timer = setTimeout(slide, 2000);
      }
    }
  });
});

// Window ready (all images loaded, but not videos!!)
$(window).ready(function() {
  // Hide loader GIF
  $('.loader').fadeOut(200);

  // Show slideshow
  $('.slideshow ul').fadeIn(200);

  // Start slideshow
  $el = $('.slideshow').find('li');
  timer = setTimeout(slide, 2000);
  slideshowSet = true;
});

// Function to slide
function slide() {
  videoSet = false;
  $el = $('.slideshow').find('li');
  $el.eq(1).add($el.eq(0)).animate({
    'left': '-=' + sWidth
  }, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 300,
    complete: function() {
      $el.eq(0).animate({
        'left': '100%'
      }, 0);
      $currentEl = $el.eq(1);
      if ($(this).index() == 1) {
        $('.slideshow ul').append($el.eq(0));

        // We chek if it's a video
        if ($(this).find('video').size() == 1) {
          //If yes we set the variable
          video = $(this).find('video')[0];
          videoSets();

          // If video can play
          if (video.canPlayType) {
            // Play video
            video.play();
          } else {
            // Error message
            alert('No html5');
          }
        } else {
          // If not a video we set timeout to next slide
          timer = setTimeout(slide, 2000);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

// Function to set all video events
function videoSets() {
  if (!videoSet) {
    videoSet = true;
    // Video ended
    video.addEventListener("ended", function() {
      timer = setTimeout(slide, 2000);
    });

    // Video Playing
    video.addEventListener("playing", function() {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      if (slidePause) {
        $('.pause').text('| |');
        video.play();
        slidePause = false;
      }
    });
  }
}

// Function to set slideshow dimensions
function setSlideDimensions(w, h, b) {
  $('.slideshow').css({
    width: w,
    'height': h,
    'padding': b
  });
  $('.slideshow ul li img, .slideshow ul li video').css({
    width: w,
    'height': h
  });
}
```

```css
.slideshow {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

.slideshow ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}

.slideshow ul li {
    position: relative;
    left: 100%;
}

.slideshow ul li:first-child {
    left: 0%;
}

video {
    background: #434343;
}

.loader {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -25px;
}

.pause {
    display: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    z-index: 100;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}


  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  

  </head>
<body>
<div class="row">

        <div class="column">

<section class="slideshow">
    <div class="pause">| |</div>
    <img src="https://c.tenor.com/5o2p0tH5LFQAAAAi/hug.gif" width="50" class="loader" />
    <ul>
        <li><img src="https://natureconservancy-h.assetsadobe.com/is/image/content/dam/tnc/nature/en/photos/Zugpsitze_mountain.jpg?crop=0%2C176%2C3008%2C1654&wid=2000&hei=1100&scl=1.504" /></li>

        <li><img src="https://mymodernmet.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Nature-Sounds-For-Well-Being-03.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/sunrise-jungle_1385-1689.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1664437209~exp=1664437809~hmac=2f34f36a7ab7d602cc4927fce5ad3063c5d945a169145d997b27e9f78f76f5ad" /></li>
        <li><img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/madakaripura-waterfall-is-tallest-waterfall-java_335224-388.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1664437263~exp=1664437863~hmac=5dfd42c39de69c5eebc5a8976d6ffc1ca733db1720a2b984a2d19b0cf5166c50" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/natural-portraits-rice-fields-mountains-indonesian-rural-areas-with-sunrise-green-morning-dew-asia_80375-80.jpg?w=1380" /></li>
             <li>
<video controls id="video1" preload>
                <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </li>
    </ul>
      </section>
          

  </div>
        <div class="column">
            </div>  </div>
          
  
  </body>
</html>
```